# Kubuntu 22.04 Plasma Workspace login event does not play notification

Tags: sound, kubuntu, 22.04, kde, notification

I have upgraded Kubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS. The notification sound of the login event does not work while all other events work fine such as **Logout**. The following screenshots demonstrate some settings:

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

Answer (score 0):

I have made a workaround, **Not A solution**, to bypass this issue by using auto start application on system login.

System Settings **>** Workspace **>** Startup and Shutsown **>** Autostart

[image]

Click on the "+Add" button, then choose, add application, to insert the following command:

```
play -v 2  ~/path/to/sound.wav
```

[image]

**To have the `play` command or app**, you have to install the `sox` package first:

```
> sudo apt install sox
```